# upstart and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: upstart

I am new to upstart and required to start a process through it. However I am getting error which is described below.

### my script contents

```
description "Server"
author "Neeraj"

expect fork

respawn
respawn limit 5 10

console log

pre-start script
    echo "`/bin/date -u`: start myappname"
end script

script
    env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/packages/myapp/target/bin
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    exec /var/packages/myapp/target/bin/myappname --local-path=/var/lib/myapp
end script

post-stop script
    echo "`/bin/date -u`: stop myappname"
end script
```

### Error after executing script

```
bash-4.3# cat /var/log/upstart/pkg-myappname.log
2016-12-07T15:15:11+0800 Wed Dec  7 07:15:11 UTC 2016: start myappname
2016-12-07T15:15:11+0800 TERM=vt102
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_JOB=pkg-myappname
_=/bin/env
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/packages/myapp/target/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2016-12-07T15:15:11+0800 /var/packages/myapp/target/bin/myappname: error while loading shared libraries: libhttp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
bash-4.3# vi /etc/init/pkg-myappname.conf
bash-4.3# cat /var/log/upstart/pkg-myappname.log
2016-12-07T15:15:11+0800 Wed Dec  7 07:15:11 UTC 2016: start myappname
2016-12-07T15:15:11+0800 TERM=vt102
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/
SHLVL=1
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_JOB=pkg-myappname
_=/bin/env
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/packages/myapp/target/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2016-12-07T15:15:11+0800 /var/packages/myapp/target/bin/myappname: error while loading shared libraries: libhttp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The issue is my executable is dependent on some shared libraries for which I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to proper location. 
But as soon as exec call happens it doesn't see the LD_LIBRARY_PATH location and reports error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Dou you have right permissions on `/var/packages/myapp/target/bin/libhttp.so`?

Comment: Yes I have right permissions on libhttp.so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own problem.
I am not sure whether its the workaround or correct way to write upstart script. But this is how I solve my problem. It is able to locate shared libraries properly now.

1. Removed script, end script.
2. Removed export statement.

Below is the working script.

```
description "Server"
author "Neeraj"

expect fork

respawn
respawn limit 5 10

console log

pre-start script
    echo "`/bin/date -u`: start myappname"
end script

env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/packages/myapp/target/bin
exec /var/packages/myapp/target/bin/myappname --local-path=/var/lib/myapp

post-stop script
    echo "`/bin/date -u`: stop myappname"
end script
```